# Configure environment files to raise errors in Continuous Integration Server (Jenkins)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I've been struggling with this one for quite a long time ... And I can't figure out how to raise the error when it happens on my Continuous Integration Server (Jenkins).

This is an example of my current environment file:

```
SomeApp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes                              = false
  config.serve_static_assets                        = true
  config.static_cache_control                       = "public, max-age=3600"
  config.whiny_nils                                 = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local                = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching          = false
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions            = false
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method              = :test
  config.active_support.deprecation                 = :stderr
  config.assets.allow_debugging                     = true
end
```

I would like to reproduce the same environment as in production, except that in this environment I would raise errors instead of redirecting to 404 / 500 / 501, etc.

But with this configuration, when Jenkins catches an error on my app, here is the output:

```
PASS (0:00:17.313) page 022/621 '/some/path?filter=with results'
FAIL (0:00:17.798) page 023/621 '/some/other/path'
   <body>You are being <a href="http://www.example.com/500.html">redirected</a>.</body>
 @ test/integration/access_all_pages_test.rb:411:in `assert_response'
   test/integration/access_all_pages_test.rb:427:in `block (2 levels) in <class:AccessAllPagesTest>'
   /var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@someapp/bundler/gems/rails-dbd26e92a7b9/activesupport/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:36:in `block in run'
   /var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@someapp/bundler/gems/rails-dbd26e92a7b9/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `_run__2667904121553047838__setup__2490215204465429087__callbacks'
   /var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@someapp/bundler/gems/rails-dbd26e92a7b9/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
   /var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@someapp/bundler/gems/rails-dbd26e92a7b9/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
   /var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@someapp/bundler/gems/rails-dbd26e92a7b9/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
   /var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@someapp/bundler/gems/rails-dbd26e92a7b9/activesupport/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in `run'
```

Instead of having the full stack trace, like I would get in my development environment...

I found this part in the documentation:

> ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions rescues any exception returned by the
>   application and renders nice exception pages if the request is local
>   or if config.consider_all_requests_local is set to true. If
>   config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions is set to false, exceptions
>   will be raised regardless.

But it didn't help.

Does anybody know how to configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ... That was my fault, I had:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from Exception, with: :handle_error

  def handle_error(exception, perform_redirect = true)
    # ...
    raise exception if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
  end
```

Changed to:

```
raise exception unless Rails.env.production?
```

Which makes more sense : If environment is not production => Raise error.

(The RAILS_ENV I use in Jenkins is not `test`, but several environments for several jobs)